# jQuery Mobile listview not working

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile

I'm trying to just create a listview on a static page. Nothing dynamic at all. Check out my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67XFq/) for an example of it not working. Also here is the code below just in case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Page Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content"><div class="content-primary">
<ul data-roll="listview">
    <li data-role="list-divider">item1</li>
    <li><a href="/">item1</a></li>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
</ul>
</div>            </div><!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul id=""><li class=""><a href="http://www.google.com" targe="" id="">My Link</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://www.google.com" targe="" id="">My Link</a></li>
</ul>                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div><!-- page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your sintax:

```
<ul data-roll="listview">
```

should be

```
<ul data-role="listview">
```

Comment: Good catch. I guess checking sintax while having food poisoning is not a good idea.